# Custom ConfigSection return null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've been following this tutorial on msdn which loads a custom configSection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute.aspx I'm doing this in asp.net and I keep getting an error on

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config =
                ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                ConfigurationUserLevel.None) as Configuration;
```

so i removed that and just used

```
UrlsSection myUrlsSection =
           ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyUrls") as UrlsSection;
```

Could someone copy and past the code from msdn and make a project in asp.net and test the code and see if they get same error or see if myUrlsSection = null and if you don't get a problem could you share what you did to make it work

Comment: Can you post your web.config entry for delcaring the section and using it? If you can, also post the declaration of your UrlsSection class.

Comment: I just copied and pasted what the tutorial had done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I tried and it works nice.

```
UrlsSection myUrlsSection =
           ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyUrls") as UrlsSection;
```

My `UrlsSection` class

```
namespace MyProject
{
    public class UrlsSection : ConfigurationSection
    {
    }
}
```

And my config entry.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MyUrls" type="MyProject.UrlsSection, MyProject" />
  </configSections>
  <MyUrls />
</configuration>
```

Comment: It worked when i use <section name="MyUrls" type="MyProject.UrlsSection" /> with out the type="MyProject.UrlSection, MyProject" MyProject at the end it says could not find specified assembly or reference and another thing when i use ConfigurationCollectionAttribute, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null it produces the same error

Comment: Why is that i had to use type="MyProject.UrlsSection instead of you're example type="MyProject.UrlsSection, MyProject".

Comment: Because this is what you specifying `type="namespace.classname, assemblyname"`. Obviously, the class `UrlsSection` is not located in your assembly `MyProject` so it doesn't work. It can still be located in the `MyProject` namespace, but not the assembly. That's why. Your project structure is different than mine, that's all.